# Eviction policy with lua for redis

Tags: redis

Is there a way to set a custom lua script as the eviction policy for Redis?

I have searched around the documentation and some other sources but i haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible.  Redis eviction policies are set in the configuration file `maxmemory-policy` (see https://redis.io/docs/reference/eviction/) and include, quoting from the documentation:

- `noeviction`: New values aren’t saved when memory limit is reached. When a database uses replication, this applies to the primary database
- `allkeys-lru`: Keeps most recently used keys; removes least recently used (LRU) keys
- allkeys-lfu: Keeps frequently used keys; removes least frequently used (LFU) keys
- `volatile-lru`: Removes least recently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- `volatile-lfu`: Removes least frequently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- `allkeys-random`: Randomly removes keys to make space for the new data added.
- `volatile-random`: Randomly removes keys with expire field set to true.
- `volatile-ttl`: Removes keys with expire field set to true and the shortest remaining time-to-live (TTL) value.